# err: CONNECTION_RESET in Chrome on form post, but only from outside network

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I started getting the following error when sending multi-part form posted data via ajax to a service on my website:

**net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

This only happens when a certain combination of characters are used in the form posted data, and the issue does not happen when I'm accessing the site directly from the server itself.

I'm basically having trouble tracking down the culprit, such as request filter, firewall, etc. I just don't know where to look, and I can't find anything in the logs that relates to it. It seems a combination of parenthesis are causing the issue, but I have no idea why.

I suppose the question is, does anyone have any ideas as to where I can start tracking down this issue?

I know this is fairly vague, but I just need a push in the right direction.

Thanks a ton.

IIS 8.5, Windows Server 2012

Comment: Are you sure your service does not crash because if those parenthesis? Does your service do input validation, error checking and reporting?

Comment: The problem is it's unpredictable. For example, all is fine for days, and then it'll start doing it. I remove the parens, issue goes away. Add them back in, issue is back. A few days later, it's working fine again... a few days after that, I can reproduce the exact same scenario. I wish I could figure out where this is being trapped/logged. I can't find anything in the logs, or perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry can't guess in the blind. Can you at least post the part with the parenthesis?

Comment: @user1447679 do you find any solution ? I am also sufering from same issue.

Comment: @gauravbhavsar Yes, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

since you have mentioned specifically in `chrome` have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083453/console-errors-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response) ?

Comment: Yes, using Chrome. However, every browser just gives it's own flavor of the same error. Truly frustrating. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

A recent comment reminded me of this question I had some time ago. In my case, the issue was with the hosting provider at a network level. The requests were getting filtered and dropped prior to reaching my server. The content was triggering a security protocol (false-positive).

So if you run into this issue and can't find a single log in IIS related to it, you have to go up a level.

Comment: I am able to see issue in HTTPERR file, but how can I fix this ? and what it means "you have to go up a level" ?

Comment: @gauravbhavsar If you have error logs you should post a new question with your errors. In my case (original question) I didn't have any error logs related to the problem.